# Ubuntu DMA Auto Activate Optimization Flag

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, drivers, hdparm

I have two NAS devices, which differ in architecture. They are connected to the same SATA disks and one of them shows better read and write performances. Okay, there could be many reasons for such behavior. I'm on SATA controller now.

When I do `hdparm -I /dev/sda` on both NAS devices I get the identical outputs except for the `DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization` flag which is enabled on the device that shows better performance and disabled on the other one.

Apparently this flag allows FIS (Frame Information Structure) operation to immediately activate, eliminating the need for a separate DMA activation FIS.

I searched whole day to find how to enable this feature but failed.

Based on this site: http://linux-ide.vger.kernel.narkive.com/pF4NtOmn/rfc-add-dma-setup-fis-auto-activate-feature I found the `ATA_FLAG_FPDMA_AA` flag here: `drivers/ata/ahci.c`, but that is all, only one mentioning of this flag.

Where is it defined?
Can I expect some performance improvement by enabling it?